# How to initialize a glm::mat4 with an array?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, glm-math

I'm using the OpenGL Mathematics Library ([glm.g-truc.net](http://glm.g-truc.net/)) and want to initialize a `glm::mat4` with a float-array.

```
float aaa[16];
glm::mat4 bbb(aaa);
```

This doesn't work.

I guess the solution is trivial, but I don't know how to do it.
I couldn't find a good documentation about glm. I would appreciate some helpful links.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Although there isn't a constructor, GLM includes make_* functions in [glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00722.html):

```
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
float aaa[16];
glm::mat4 bbb = glm::make_mat4(aaa);
```

Comment: Also don't forget to ensure that the source array is stored **column-wise**, otherwise you will need to add `glm::mat4 bbbT = glm::make_mat4(aaa); glm::mat4 bbb = glm::transpose(bbbT);`

Answer (score 11):

You can also directly copy the memory:

```
float aaa[16] = {
   1, 2, 3, 4,
   5, 6, 7, 8,
   9, 10, 11, 12,
   13, 14, 15, 16
};
glm::mat4 bbb;

memcpy( glm::value_ptr( bbb ), aaa, sizeof( aaa ) );
```

Comment: Do I need to type "`std::memcpy()`"?  Where is this `memcpy()` function?

Answer (score 5):

You could write an adapter function:

```
template<typename T>
tvec4<T> tvec4_from_t(const T *arr) {
    return tvec4<T>(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
}

template<typename T>
tmat4<T> tmat4_from_t(const T *arr) {
    return tmat4<T>(tvec4_from_t(arr), tvec4_from_t(arr + 4), tvec4_from_t(arr + 8), tvec4_from_t(arr + 12));
}


// later
float aaa[16];
glm::mat4 bbb = tmac4_from_t(aaa);
```